# Getting "Subquery returned more than 1 value error message " while using Case statement inside Where Not In

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

If I do

```
SELECT * FROM cte1 c
    WHERE c.GrantNumber NOT IN
    (

      SELECT t1.nai_grant_number FROM #temp t1

    )
```

This works fine.

But if I do

```
SELECT * FROM cte1 c
    WHERE c.GrantNumber NOT IN
    (
      CASE WHEN 
                @AutoRenewalChk = 1 THEN
                 (

                     SELECT t1.nai_grant_number FROM #temp t1
                 ) END          
    )
```

getting error

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 33 Subquery returned more than 1
>   value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

What is the reason? Cannot we use a case statement like the above?

Thanks

Comment: What happens when you remove the extra parentheses after `then` and before `end`?

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 62
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 65
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM cte1 AS c
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1 FROM #temp AS t1 
  WHERE t1.nai_grant_number = CASE @AutoRenewalChk 
    WHEN 1 THEN c.GrantNumber END
);
```

Here is why NOT IN will not work here. Try these two queries. Would you expect the same result in each case?

```
SELECT x FROM (SELECT x = 1) AS x WHERE x NOT IN 
    (SELECT y = 2);

SELECT x FROM (SELECT x = 1) AS x WHERE x NOT IN 
    (SELECT y = 2 UNION ALL SELECT NULL);
```

Adding a possible NULL here (which Dan P suggested as an ELSE in his answer, or if #temp can contain even a single row where nai_grant_number is NULL) completely changes the semantics of NOT IN. Therefore just about any time you are thinking about writing a NOT IN query, you should re-think it as a NOT EXISTS (or LEFT OUTER JOIN, or other struct).

Answer (score 0):

Just like the error says, your query iS returning more than one row. If you change your subs select to select top 1... It will work

Comment: But it works if i donot use the case statement..problem comes when i use the case syntax

Comment: Case expects a scalar result. You can't say case when 1 then (1,2,3). You can only return one value

Comment: sorry i didnot get..what is sCa?

Comment: TOP 1 will not work if he has multiple values that he wants in the NOT IN clause.

Comment: I agree. I was simply answering the OP actual question: namely: "Why is this happening." How come there is no stackoverflow badge for answering a question on an iPad? It could be called the Masochist badge.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead as others have mentioned the CASE When works on a single column or value not a rowset.  Assuming c.GrantNumber is never null this should work for you.

```
SELECT * FROM cte1 c 
WHERE c.GrantNumber NOT IN 
( 
    SELECT DISTINCT
        CASE WHEN @AutoRenewalChk = 1
            THEN t1.nai_grant_number
            ELSE NULL
        END
    FROM #temp t1
)
```

Comment: I don't think this does what you expect then @AutoRenewalChk = 0. NOT IN does not play nicely if NULL is possible as the comparison value.

Comment: Can easily add a sub case for CASE WEHN @AutoRenwalChk = 0 select something else.  It's a little unclear exactly what he is going for but this is at least a start for him to get back a list of values to be put in the NOT IN clause.  And if NULL is possible he can change to -1 or -999 or some magic number as well.

Comment: I think you missed my point - you should never use NOT IN if NULL can be in the output. This is also true in this case even if you use a "magic number" (which you should also strive to stay away from). If nai_grant_number is nullable you'll also have unexpected results.

Comment: It's really you're only option to use NULL or a magic number if #temp has multiple nai_grant_numbers.  As I said It's not clear if this should have multiple or only TOP 1 record.  From his output he is getting multiple records and nai_grant_numbers could be returning 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc in which case TOP 1 will not do.  In lua of the question and circumstances he has to deal with null or a magic number.  He could also create a sub query to strip out the IS NOT NULL.  OR IS <> magic number.

Comment: I wasn't saying that TOP 1 is an alternative to what you wrote. I'm suggesting that NOT EXISTS is a much better alternative to NOT IN. NOT EXISTS doesn't care if the comparison column is NULL, which always has the potential to cause problems with NOT IN. Did you try your query? I did, and while it returned the right results if `@AutoRenewalChk` was 1, it did *NOT* produce any results when the parameter was 0. Create some sample data (e.g. 1 and 2 in the cte1 table, and 1 in the #temp table) and compare your query to mine, when the `@AutoRenewalChk` param is 0, 1 and NULL.

Comment: I guess my point is that if he has multiple values coming back which he want's in his NOT IN clause there isn't much else you can do as the CASE WHEN acts on a single column, single value, scalar object.  This is the only route to go if the NOT IN clause has multiple values...and I'd expect he truly does have multiple values or he wouldn't be using a NOT IN clause and we just be using a where <> clause.

Comment: Still missing my point. NOT IN ***IS NOT THE ONLY ROUTE*** - please try the NOT EXISTS query I wrote and compare our results.

Comment: His pseudo code doesn't matter. NOT IN and NULL don't work together. Please read this IN FULL. http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/ - and actually try our two queries.

Comment: -1 because, as much as you don't want to believe me, your query works great when the parameter is 1, but in any other case it does not work.

Comment: I agree maybe NOT EXISTS is better route to go but either way the case statement can be changed to account for that WHEN AutoRenewalChk IS NULL WHEN AutoRenewalChk  = 0 etc

Comment: I was just trying to give a helpful description and possible solution to problem.  Problem not fully being understood or Question not being stated clearly this is best I could come up with.

Comment: I added an example to my answer that shows why NOT IN is a bad idea here. In case you don't believe me and in case you haven't actually tried your query.

Comment: I'm starting to see your point.  with the NOT EXISTS.  I appologize but will leave answer as is hopefully not a lot of down votes for the attempt.